# How to select all other values in an array except the ith element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function using an array value represented as

```
 markers[i]
```

**How can I select all other values in an array except this one?**

The purpose of this is to reset all other Google Maps images to their original state but highlight a new one by changing the image.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`Array​.prototype​.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to get an array of elements excluding this one.

This affects the array permanently, so if you don't want that, create a copy first.

```
var origArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var cloneArray = origArray.slice();
var i = 3;

cloneArray.splice(i,1);

console.log(cloneArray.join("---"));
```

Comment: @JackDamery yes it will, so you will need to create a copy.

Comment: @DhruvPathak Bah, no. `slice()` creates new object, doesn't affect original array at all. The only functions having data impact here are `join()` and `splice()`, but they are called after `slice()`.

Comment: @Ty221 My comment was regarding `splice`, hence created a copy using `slice` before doing a splice, so that splice doesn't affect the original array.

Comment: [Link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on `slice()`

Comment: good solution, the only caveat is that it won't work with nested loops. If you have a nested loop splice will modify the array and you nested index value will be off

Answer (score 29):

You can use ECMAScript 5 **[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var current = 2;

var itemsWithoutCurrent = items.filter(function(x) { return x !== current; });
```

There can be any comparison logics instead of `x !== current`. For example, you can compare object properties.

If you work with primitives, you can also create a custom function like `except` which will introduce this functionality:

```
Array.prototype.except = function(val) {
    return this.filter(function(x) { return x !== val; });        
}; 

// Usage example:
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].except(2)); // 1, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: This would behave differently if array values are all same i.e. [2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: This removes elements with the value of 2 not the element at ith position

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the second callback parameter in [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const exceptIndex = 3;
const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
const filteredItems = items.filter((value, index) => exceptIndex !== index);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use  `slice()` Method

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var citrus = fruits.slice(1,3);
```

The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

Comment: Definitely the best way! +1

Comment: You would need to call slice more than once and combine the sliced arrays if the item you want to remove is not the first or the last element. To remove element at fruits[x]: `const result = [...fruits.slice(1,x-1), ...fruits.slice(x+1, fruits.length)]`

Answer (score 2):

Another way this can be done is by using filter and slice Array methods.

```
let array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
let leave = 2;

// method 1
console.log(array.filter((e,i) => i !== leave));
// logs [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];

//method 2
console.log([...array.slice(0, leave), ...array.slice(leave+1, array.length)]);
// logs [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will return a new array with all elements except the element at the specified index:

```
    const everythingBut = (array, i) => { /*takes an array and an index as arguments*/
        let notIArray = []; /*creates new empty array*/
        let beforeI = array.slice(0, i); /*creates subarray of all elements before array[i]*/
        let afterI = array.slice(i+1,); /*creates subarray of all elements after array[i]*/
        notIArray = [...beforeI, ...afterI]; /*add elements before and after array[i] to empty array*/
        return notIArray; /*returns new array with array[i] element excluded*/
    };
```

For example:

```
    let array = [1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 2, 6]
    everythingBut(array, 2); /*exclude array[2]*/
    // -> [1, 2, 7, 9, 11, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Array.prototype.slice() and Array.prototype.concat() in using startingArray.slice(desiredStartIndex, exclusionIndex).concat(startingArray.slice(exclusionIndex+1)) to exclude the item whose index is exclusionIndex.
E.g., if you have a startingArray of [0, 1, 2] and want a desiredArray of [0, 2], then you can do as follows:

```
startingArray = [0, 1, 2];
desiredStartIndex = 0;
exclusionIndex = 1;
desiredEndIndex = 2;
desiredArray = startingArray.slice(desiredStartIndex, 
exclusionIndex).concat(startingArray.slice(exclusionIndex+1));
```

Answer (score -1):

With ECMAScript 5

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const removeAt = 1;
const newArray = [...array].splice(removeAt, 1);
```

Comment: `[...array].splice(removeAt, 1);` returns the removed element